# SSE не дает прироста

Tags: оптимизация, visual-studio-2015

Разбираюсь с SIMD. Собрал пример, и начал делать тесты.
Если компилировать Release x86 дает заметный прирост SSE. AVX не много или вообще не чего.

- fun = 19320
- fun sse= 6333
- fun avx= 14490

При компиляции Release x64 прироста нету.

- fun = 6339
- fun sse= 6337
- fun avx= 15792

Я не правильно делаю тесты? Разве не должен быть прирост для Release x64.
Насколько я понимаю тут выполняются 4 операции за 1 заход но почему тогда нету прироста?
Почему AVX медленнее?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <ratio>
    #include <chrono>

    void fun(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c[i] = sqrt(a[i] * a[i] +
                b[i] * b[i]) + 0.5f;
        }
    }

    inline void fun_sse(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n)
    {
        int i, k;
        __m128 x, y, z;
        __m128 *aa = (__m128 *)a;
        __m128 *bb = (__m128 *)b;
        __m128 *cc = (__m128 *)c;
        /* Предполагаем, что n кратно 4 */
        k = n / 4;
        z = _mm_set_ps1(0.5f);
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            x = _mm_mul_ps(*aa, *aa);
            y = _mm_mul_ps(*bb, *bb);
            x = _mm_add_ps(x, y);
            x = _mm_sqrt_ps(x);
            *cc = _mm_add_ps(x, z);
            aa++;
            bb++;
            cc++;
        }
    }

    void fun_avx(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n)
    {
        int i, k;
        __m256 x, y;
        __m256 *aa = (__m256 *)a;
        __m256 *bb = (__m256 *)b;
        __m256 *cc = (__m256 *)c;
        k = n / 8;
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            x = _mm256_mul_ps(*aa, *aa);
            y = _mm256_mul_ps(*bb, *bb);
            x = _mm256_add_ps(x, y);
            *cc = _mm256_sqrt_ps(x);
            aa++;
            bb++;
            cc++;
        }
    }

    enum { N = 1024, NREPS = 10 };

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {

        int i;
        float *a, *b, *c;
        double t;
        a = (float *)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float) * N, 16);
        b = (float *)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float) * N, 16);
        c = (float *)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float) * N, 16);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            a[i] = 1.0; b[i] = 2.0;
        }

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (i = 0; i < NREPS; i++)
            fun(a, b, c, N); /* fun(a, b, c, N); */
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "fun = " << duration.count() << std::endl;

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (i = 0; i < NREPS; i++)
            fun_sse(a, b, c, N); /* fun(a, b, c, N); */
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "fun sse= " << duration.count() << std::endl;

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (i = 0; i < NREPS; i++)
            fun_avx(a, b, c, N); /* fun(a, b, c, N); */
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "fun avx= " << duration.count() << std::endl;

        _mm_free(a); _mm_free(b); _mm_free(c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Блин) Теперь вообще не понятно как использовать SIMD если компилятор сам все делает. Я хочу использовать его для DSP. Если я делаю "предвычесления" в массив для того чтобы потом загнать в SSE получается медленнее из-за того что пишу в память. Если не чего не трогаю выходит быстрей. Компилятор умней меня :( Открыл для себя целый новый дивный мир.

Answer (score 1):

Во всех подобных спорах с компилятором и секундомером следует начинать с разбора машинного кода, который сгенерировал компилятор. Полагаю, что в последнем случае, он банально выполнил те же оптимизации, которые вы делали вручную.

*В качестве замечания в сторону* - использование `malloc` в `C++` может привести к трудноуловимым ошибкам. В C++ для работы с динамической памятью есть `new` и `delete`

Answer (score 1):

Причина в следующем. Во-первых, компилятор, конечно же, пытается оптимизировать через SSE. Для режима x86 туповатый VS-2015 генерирует бред, пытаясь развернуть цикл на 8 итераций и делая целую кучу ненужных телодвижений. При этом он читает по 64 бита за раз, а не по 128, а потом как дурак распихивает всё по нужным регистрам. Почему? Потому что (то ли я что-то не понимаю, то ли разработчики из Microsoft) **он конвертирует ваши числа в double!!!** (я правда не знаю, почему, скорее всего ошибка компилятора, коих у VS-2015 десятки).

Во-вторых, в режиме x64 компилятор делает более совершенный код, разворачивая цикл на 16 шагов и делая почти такой же код, как в Вашей оптимизации вручную. Он воспринимает ваши массивы правильно, как float. Поэтому разницы почти не будет.

Компиляторы Intel, GCC и CLang Ваш код компилировать отказываются, так что ничего больше не могу сказать.